# Android, remove custom button border

Tags: android, background, imagebutton

I used this selector code for my custom button (simple.xml)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedpressed" />
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" />
  </selector>
```

But on my ImageButton I don't know how to remove border. I want to show only my images not to show border around button.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replace

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
  android:src="@drawable/simple"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

with :

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
  android:background="@drawable/simple"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

And work

Answer (score 4):

Set `android:background` rather than `android:drawable`.

Comment: I replace android:drawable="@drawable/focused" with android:background="@drawable/focused" , but I get force close error. Thanks

Comment: In xlm file I use :
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
  android:src="@drawable/simple"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />